# iOS Sockets library listen support

Tags: codenameone

I am finding some conflicting articles, some are old, about CN1 not having Sockets but I see the library com.codename1.io.Socket.  I have seen some articles saying it works on Android as well but not iOS.  I need the capability to listen on a socket on iOS and was hoping to use an internal library.  The shannah/CN1Sockets project doesn't appear to support listening.

From 2014, https://www.codenameone.com/blog/sockets-multiline-trees.html , and lists non iOS support.  Any update on this?

Codova/Phonegap does have a few libraries and someone implements Chrome's TCP/UDP API for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Server sockets are very problematic across platforms as the iOS implementation is radically different from the Android implementation and a bit challenging to implement using the `listen` paradigm.

It's probably possible to implement server sockets on iOS but because there wasn't much demand and this required some work we chose not to do it. It's also not very useful ans phones move around/change networks. You won't get a stable IP to work against anyway. A better way would be to initiate communication from the client and then communicate back. Notice you won't be able to use a server socket in a background process in iOS anyway as the process will be killed when sent to background!

The only Cordova implementation I found is this: https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcpServer

You can probably use that with native interfaces or just use it as a baseline for a pull request to implement server sockets on iOS but again it's very unlikely that what you are trying to do with server sockets won't work due to iOS limitations.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Looking in to Pushkit.  I see now that iOS 10 dropped VoIP background tasks.

Comment: We support background execution for common use cases but running a server on the device isn't one of them. VoIP generally works by proxying through a push server.

Comment: I wanted to make a cross platform peer to peer communications system.  I may end up doing with BTLE by finishing up the Cordova implementation so I can use  peripheral and central modes.

Comment: Peer to peer is generally problematic with mobiles as they might change bands with no warning e.g. go from wifi to cell and back wiith no real reason.